# C++11 strange behavior with classes, pointers and global scope declarations

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++11

```
[Global Scope]

myClass *objA, *objB, *obj;
int objnum;
```

I want to switch between `objA` and `objB` and assign them alternatively to `obj`, so in `main()` I have:

```
int main()
{
  objA = new myClass(parameters...);
  objB = new myClass(parameters...);

  // start with objA;
  objnum = 0;
  obj = objA;
}
```

At some point a function is called that switches between the two objects:

```
void switchObjects()
{
  if (++objnum > 1) objnum = 0;
  obj = objnum == 0 ? objA : objB;
}
```

And in the function where I use the object, I have:

```
void doYourJob()
{
  int res = obj->work();
}
```

Now the weird thing is that if I don't assign `obj` to either `objA` or `objB`, it still works. I would expect an exception, instead. Even if I do `obj = NULL;`, it still works! What's this voodoo?

OK, I could provide a different example that brings to the same result, without using a NULL pointer:

```
myClass *obj[2];
int objnum;

void switchObject()
{
  if (++objnum > 1) objnum = 0;
}

void doYourJob()
{
  res = obj[objnum]->work();
}

int main()
{
  obj[0] = new myClass(parameters...);
  obj[1] = new myClass(parameters...);

  objnum = 0;
}
```

With the above code, regardless of the value of objnum, I still get both objects working together, even if I'm calling `work()` on only one instance.

And if I replace the function `doYourJob()` with this:

```
void doYourJob()
{
  int res1 = obj[0]->work();
  int res2 = obj[1]->work();
}
```

I always get the results doubled, as if I were calling the function `work()` twice on every object.

Comment: You can't expect *anything* from an undefined program.

Comment: Calling a member function on a null pointer is undefined behaviour. It will often work if the member function doesn't actually use any class members.

Comment: I posted a different example that has nothing to do with null pointers, anybody can give me a clue?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "Works" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    X* x = nullptr;
    x->foo();
}
```

With most compilers and on most platforms, this code will appear to work fine, despite having called `foo` on a null pointer. However, the behaviour is technically *undefined*. That is, the C++ language gives no restrictions about what might happen if you do this.

Why does it work? Well, calling a member function only requires knowing the type of the object it is being called on. We know that `x` points at an `X`, so we know what function to call: `X::foo`. In many cases, it may be difficult or even impossible to know if a pointer points at a real object, so the compiler just lets it happen. The body of the function, in this case, doesn't actually depend on the `X` object actually existing, so it just works. This isn't something you can depend on though.

Comment: I have updated my post with a different example that gives the same result. Could you please give it a look? Does it still have to do with null pointers?

Comment: @MarkMiles [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/kI36Bj). You'll need to post a new question with a short, compilable example for anybody to help.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce it either on a simpler example... My actual program is way bigger, involves many memory allocations, timers, callbacks, sockets, real-time audio, etc... The problem might be somewhere else. I tried to simplify it in this example ( http://ideone.com/bjQ1s8 ) but in my actual program whatever index I use with the class pointers I don't get any error and it still works.

Comment: @MarkMiles Is there anything about the output of that program that you don't expect? As I said, if you call a member function on a pointer to an invalid object, you get undefined behaviour. It might appear to work. You shouldn't expect an error.

Comment: What I don't expect is that in my program if I call only `obj[0]->Work(x, y);` I get the results of both objects as if I were calling the functions of both objects.

Comment: @MarkMiles Sorry, [still can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/saFyvT)! If you can't figure out how to simplify it, I can only suggest that you trace through your program or run a debugger on it.

Comment: I just realized that my previous example was wrong, here's a corrected version: http://ideone.com/RhYuZO

Comment: @MarkMiles First, `objnum` is `0`. You call `Work` on that object. Then you call `switchObject`, so `objnum` is `1`.  Then you call `Work` on that object. Then the next iteration of the for loop begins and `objnum` is *still* `1`. You call `Work` on that object.... - you're just missing a call to `switchObject`.

Comment: @MarkMiles By the way, don't forget to `delete` your dynamically allocated objects.